# How to get a non intersecting Overdue + Next 7 Days agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I've been trying to get a agenda with two segments: Everything that is overdue and a view of the next 7 days.

For now my agenda looks like this:

```lisp
 org-agenda-custom-commands
         '(("t" "Agenda + Overdue"
            (
             (agenda ""
                     ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Overdue")
                      (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline :scheduled))
                      ;; FIXME: if this is less than today, it makes
                      ;; org-agenda ignore overdue items if set to anything other than NIL
                      (org-agenda-start-day "-1d") ; skip due today, shown below
                      (org-scheduled-past-days 10000)
                      (org-deadline-past-days 10000)
                      (org-agenda-span 1)
                      (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
                      (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
                      (org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
                      (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)
                      (org-agenda-format-date "")  ;; Skip the date
                      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
                      ;; (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if )
                      ))

             (agenda ""
                     ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Next 7 Days")
                      (org-agenda-span 7)
                      (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
                      (org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
                      (org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
                      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
                      (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline :scheduled))
                      (org-scheduled-past-days 0)
                      (org-deadline-past-days 0)
                      (org-deadline-warning-days 3)))

             )
            ))
```

### Example

For this org file (today is 29/01/2023) :

```
* Overdue
** TODO More than yesterday overdue
SCHEDULED: <2023-01-27 Fri>
** TODO Yesterday Overdue
SCHEDULED: <2023-01-28 Sat>
* Today
** Due Today
SCHEDULED: <2023-01-29 Sun>
* Future
** Due Tomorrow
SCHEDULED: <2023-01-30 Mon>
** Due the next day
SCHEDULED: <2023-01-31 Tue>
```

I see this:

```
Overdue

  file:       Scheduled:  TODO Yesterday Overdue

===============================================================
Next 7 Days
Sunday     29 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Today
Monday     30 January 2023 W05
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Tomorrow
Tuesday    31 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due the next day
Wednesday   1 February 2023
Thursday    2 February 2023
Friday      3 February 2023
Saturday    4 February 2023
```

Instead of this (edited by hand to match desired output):

```
Overdue

  file:       Sched. 2x:  TODO More than yesterday overdue
  file:       Sched. 1x:  TODO Yesterday Overdue

=============================================================
Next 7 Days
Sunday     29 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Today
Monday     30 January 2023 W05
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Tomorrow
Tuesday    31 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due the next day
Wednesday   1 February 2023
Thursday    2 February 2023
Friday      3 February 2023
Saturday    4 February 2023
```

Also when not setting `org-agenda-start-day` I get this:

```
Overdue

  file:       Sched. 2x:  TODO More than yesterday overdue
  file:       Sched. 1x:  TODO Yesterday Overdue
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Today

=================================================================
Next 7 Days
Sunday     29 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Today
Monday     30 January 2023 W05
  file:       Scheduled:  Due Tomorrow
Tuesday    31 January 2023
  file:       Scheduled:  Due the next day
Wednesday   1 February 2023
Thursday    2 February 2023
Friday      3 February 2023
Saturday    4 February 2023
```

Which is not missing entries, but has them duplicated across today and overdue.

I can't get it **not** show TODO's due today on the Overdue section or be missing overdue items.

I've tried the option `(org-agenda-start-day "-1d")`, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Is this a bug (I've poked around in org-agenda's code but couldn't pinpoint anything obvious) or is there some way to get the desired behavior?

### General Info

I'm using spacemacs development, with org-mode 9.6 @ emacs 28.1

p.s.: using `tags+todo` instead of `agenda` is not viable because I have a `CREATED` property on most of my entries, and using `SCHEDULED<"<+0d>"` also selects them even if they aren't really scheduled.

Comment: Hi - could you edit your question with a sample org-mode file and a desired agenda output? You've explained _mostly_ what you wanted, but there's so much flexibility and variables that what you asked for a is a bit ambiguous, still.

Comment: @Trevoke Can you take a look? (forgot to tag you before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this felt like a defect, but I think this is actually intended behavior somehow. Anyway, here's how I got working what I think is what you want. Basically it's a custom skip function that will only keep things that are overdue starting... Right before midnight, beginning of day today. Let me know if this does the trick for you.

```
(defun timestamp-midnight (timestamp)
  (let ((decoded (decode-time timestamp)))
    (setf (nth 0 decoded) 0)
    (setf (nth 1 decoded) 0)
    (setf (nth 2 decoded) 0)
    (apply #'encode-time decoded)))

(defun org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-earlier ()
  "If this function returns nil, the current match should not be skipped.
Otherwise, the function must return a position from where the search
should be continued."
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (scheduled-seconds (org-time-string-to-seconds (org-entry-get nil "SCHEDULED")))
          (now (time-to-seconds (timestamp-midnight (current-time)))))
      (and scheduled-seconds
           (>= scheduled-seconds now)
           subtree-end))))


(let ((org-agenda-files '("/tmp/test-agenda/"))
      (org-agenda-custom-commands
       '(("t" "Agenda + Overdue"
          ((agenda ""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Overdue")
                    (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline :scheduled))
                    (org-scheduled-past-days 10000)
                    (org-deadline-past-days 10000)
                    (org-agenda-span 1)
                    (org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
                    (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)
                    (org-agenda-skip-function 'org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-earlier)))          
           (agenda ""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Next 7 Days")
                    (org-agenda-span 7)
                    (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
                    (org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
                    (org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
                    (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
                    (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline :scheduled))
                    (org-scheduled-past-days 0)
                    (org-deadline-past-days 0)
                    (org-deadline-warning-days 3))))))))
  (org-agenda nil "t"))
```

Comment: Thats it! I thought of using a custom skip function, but was at a loss on how to implement it.